# Adding orElse function to firstWhere method

Tags: dart

I am trying to add the onElse function to the itterator.firstWhere method but I cannot get the syntax right.

I have tried something like

```dart
List<String> myList = 

String result = myList.firstWhere((o) => o.startsWith('foo'), (o) => null);
```

But the compiler has an error of

> 1 positional arguments expected, but 2 found

I am sure it is a simple syntax problem, but it has me stumped

Answer (score 345):

In case someone came here thanks to google, searching about how to return `null` if `firstWhere` found nothing, when your app is **Null Safe**, use the new method of `package:collection` called `firstWhereOrNull`.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // You have to add this manually, for some reason it cannot be added automatically

// somewhere...
MyStuff? stuff = someStuffs.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.id == 'Cat');
```

About the method:
https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/firstWhereOrNull.html

Comment: For some reason `package:collection/collection.dart` was not imported automatically, but after reading this and added it manually all my tests are passing again. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sad for I have to have one more dependency for this small feature. Dart has yet so a long way to go.

Comment: The best one by far

Comment: This will help some people, but it does not answer the question. The question concerns implementing `orElse` in `firstWhere` and a compiler error about too many positional arguments.

Comment: @JohnWang You don't have to add any dependency, this package comes with dart, for some reason is not imported automatically tho ._.

Comment: I think this is just a extension function, this is why you need to add it manually.

Comment: do not forget to add it to pubspec.yaml as a dependency:  
collection: ^1.16.0

Comment: @Defarine where is the '1.16.0' part coming from? Should it be monitored and updated every time when a new version of 'collection' comes out, or is it acceptable to just specify 'collection: any' instead and leave Flutter to its own devices, given that apparently collection is a part of Flutter?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't gets added automatically it's because collection is an external package, that needs to be added to the pubspec.

One can do that by running `flutter pub add collection`

Answer (score 111):

'orElse' is a named optional argument.

```dart
void main() {
  checkOrElse(['bar', 'bla']);
  checkOrElse(['bar', 'bla', 'foo']);
}

void checkOrElse(List<String> values) {
  String result = values.firstWhere((o) => o.startsWith('foo'), orElse: () => '');

  if (result != '') {
    print('found: $result');
  } else {
    print('nothing found');
  }
}
```

Comment: That produces the compile error "The argument type '(dynamic) → <bottom>' cannot be assigned to the parameter type '() → String'"

Comment: I just wanted to add that not providing an orElse method will not return null but throw a StateError: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.1/dart-collection/ListQueue/firstWhere.html

Comment: A prior comment is not correct. Returning `null` from `orElse` does not trigger the StateError. Thus, `orElse: () => null` will not trigger the StateError and works totally as expected. Something like `orElse: null`, however, is the same as leaving the parameter out and defaults to the StateError when `test` fails.

Comment: @juanitogan, @Fabian's statement *is* correct. Fabian says that *not* providing an `orElse` will throw if nothing is found. You're making a different point. I would edit your comment, since that's not what was said. I know @Fabian is correct, because that `StateError` is what brought me here. :)

Comment: @WillHaslett, Yes, Fabian's statement is correct. I suspect I was referring to a comment that has since been deleted... but can't say I remember for sure.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. OP asked for syntax.

Comment: This answer does indeed exactly answer the question as written: "adding orElse function to firstWhere method" and addresses the symptom: compiler error "1 positional arguments expected, but 2 found".

Answer (score 21):

Using cast<E?>(), you can do this without adding dependencies:

```
void main() {
  List<String> myList = ["Hello", "World"];

  String? result = myList.cast<String?>().firstWhere((o) => o!.startsWith('foo'), orElse: () => null);

  print(result ?? "No result");
}
```

You can try this on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true).

Comment: This should actually be marked as the answer! Thank you :3

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the collections package directly:
Run the command below, which will add it to your pubspec.yaml file:

$ flutter pub add collection

ref: [collection: ^1.16.0](https://pub.dev/packages/collection/install)