# How to find an element in a dart list

Tags: dart

I have a dart list of objects, every of which contains `book_id` property, and I want to find an element of that list by the `book_id` field.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use firstWhere method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html

```
void main() {
  final list = List<Book>.generate(10, (id) => Book(id));

  Book findBook(int id) => list.firstWhere((book) => book.id == id);

  print(findBook(2).name);  
  print(findBook(4).name);
  print(findBook(6).name);  
}

class Book{
  final int id;

  String get name => "Book$id";

  Book(this.id);
}

/*
Output:
Book2
Book4
Book6
*/
```

Comment: What if requested item is not in the list? it throws exception!

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi handle exception or refactoring `findBook` for nullable

Answer (score 18):

### Null-Safe approach (handling no-element error)

If the searched item might or might not be in the array, with null safety I personally prefer to use `.where` on lists - it filters through the array and returns a list.

```
  var myListFiltered = myList.where((e) => e.id == id);
  if (myListFiltered.length > 0) {
    // Do stuff with myListFiltered.first
  } else {
    // Element is not found
  }
```

The benefit of this approach is that you'll always get an array and there won't be an issue with element not being found or trying to return `null` through `orElse` callback:

```
The return type 'Null' isn't a 'FooBar', as required by the closure's context.
```

### Refactoring the finder logic into a helper method

Since the task of finding an element by id in a list of objects is quite a common one, I like to extract that logic into helpers file, for example:

```
class Helpers {
  static findById(list, String id) {
    var findById = (obj) => obj.id == id;
    var result = list.where(findById);
    return result.length > 0 ? result.first : null;
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var obj = Helpers.findById(myList, id);
if (obj == null) return; //? Exn: element is not found
```

Answer (score 14):

A lot has been said already, but I want to add my best way to do this. if it's possible that the item doesn't exist in the list, import the iterable extension and use `firstWhereOrNull1` on the list.

```
import 'package:collection/src/iterable_extensions.dart';

myList.firstWhereOrNull((item) => item.id == id))
```

Comment: I had to import `import 'package:collection/collection.dart'` — [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66956466/506695).

Comment: To be clear, you need to import the collection package from pub.dev to use "firstWhereOrNull) method. Link : https://pub.dev/packages/collection

Answer (score 6):

You should add orElse to avoid exeption:

```
list.firstWhere(
 (book) => book.id == id,
 orElse: () => null,
);
```

Comment: Null is not a valid return type of orElse.

Comment: Yes, null is not a valid orElse return type, but it does provide a way to avoid an exception.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to add `orElse` to every use of `firstWhere`, with Dart 2.7+, you can create a handy little extension to handle this:

```
extension IterableX<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T safeFirstWhere(bool Function(T) test) {
    final sublist = where(test);
    return sublist.isEmpty ? null : sublist.first;
  }
}
```

Which can then be used as such:

```
final books = List<Book>.generate(10, (id) => Book(id));
final matchingBooks = books.safeFirstWhere((book) => book.id == id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the extension version. I changed it a little bit to avoid looping through the entire list if only one item is needed

`extension IterableX<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T) test) {
    T? firstItem;
    for (var item in this) {
      if (test(item)) {
        firstItem = item;
        break;
      }
    }

    return firstItem;
  }
}`

Comment: Error : A value of type 'T?' can't be returned from the method 'safeFirstWhere' because it has a return type of 'T'.

Answer (score 3):

```
void main(){
  
  List lights=[
      {"id":1,"color":"yellow"},
      {"id":2,"color":"green"},
      {"id":3,"color":"red"}
  ];

int searchId = 2;
var colr = lights.firstWhere((x) => x['id'] == searchId, orElse:() => {"color" : "Color Not found"})['color'];

print(colr); 
}
```

The above code searches the obj list, using [firstWhere](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html). If not found returns text 'Color not found'

Answer (score 1):

This is my custom implementation to return either the Element if found or null if not:

```
abstract class HasId {
  String get id;
}

T? findById<T>(List<HasId> list, String? id) {
  final elementsFound = list.where((element) => element.id == id);
  if (elementsFound.isEmpty) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return elementsFound.first as T;
  }
}
```