# Access member by another member in a Class List Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find the `name` using the `id` in modelList from the example below.

```
class Example{
  List<Abc> modelList = [
    Abc(1, "John"),
    Abc(2, "Christine"),
    Abc(3, "Steven"),
    Abc(4, "Others"),
  ];
  
  myFun(){
    int idToFind = 4;
    String foundString = // Some iterable function??
  }
}

class Abc{
  int id;
  String name;
  Abc(this.id, this.name);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find an element in dart list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920284/how-to-find-an-element-in-dart-list)

Comment: It does but in-directly. I saw that post but had me confused. After learning the answer here the post made more sense.

Comment: The answer accepted by you is the same as what the above link has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String foundString = modelList.firstWhere((abc) => abc.id == idToFind).name;
```