# How to search through the Object list with the property in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the list like:-

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]
```

what is the most elegant way to find the object where the `obj.id == "id"` in above list in dart?

Answer (score 2):

One way is with `.firstWhere` method.

For example

```
class Foo{
 final String id;
 Foo(this.id);
}

main(){
 //Creates Foo objects with ID from 1 to 5;
 List<Foo> foos = List.generate(5, (index) => Foo("${index+1}"));  
 String idToSearch = "3";
 Foo foundFoo = foos.firstWhere((foo) => foo.id == idToSearch));
 print(foundFoo.id); //3
}
```

Comment: `where` returns a list, so you would need to call `first` on it. Or use the `firstWhere` method to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `firstWhere()`.

```
final idToFind = 5;
final list = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5];
final item = list.firstWhere((obj) => obj.id == idToFind);
```

Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a catch using `first` and `firstWhere`, because they will throw if the list is empty or no items match the condition (also applies to `single` and `singleWhere`). So you'll want to wrap your code in a try/catch.

Alternatively, you can use the `orElse` callback in `firstWhere`. If a default value can be returned, `orElse` should return it otherwise you might want to return `null` (and cast your list before using `firstWhere` if the item type is not nullable).

Eg

```dart
/* assuming list is an Iterable<T> */

final item = list.cast<T?>().firstWhere(
   (o) => o.id == idToFind,
   orElse: () => null
);

if (item != null) {
   // a match was found
}
```

Comment: You can also use `firstWhereOrNull` as descibed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504074/adding-orelse-function-to-firstwhere-method